# Align button top to textview end

Tags: android, android-layout

This might be a silly silly question, nonetheless, has successfully driven me crazy. 
[image]

How would one go about getting this kind of an alignment?

1. Checkbox
2. TextView - Aligned to top of checkbox and to its right
3. Button/ImageButton - Aligned to end of TextView

What layout would I use? How would I set the widths of these elements as some sort of a percentage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:text="yourtext" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_icon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/yourimageview" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="bsdvdsjvbdsjfvcbdsvjdsbvbcvm vm,cxvmjbvjcbvjxvbxncvcxvxcbzbdfgdfzzgdfgdfgdfzgdfzvgzxvbnxcjkdsbvckjdsvbchsvgdhjsdvbndsbchjsdfgdshfgdshcb nsxbc" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:text="CheckBox" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Won't work if layout is bigger than the TextView. Then button will be at the bottom of the layout, not the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

Place your textview and checkbox in a horizontal alignment in your html.
Set the **android:gravity='bottom'**  attribute for the checkbox.
To set the widths, use the **android:gravity**  attribute.  The numbers you use for gravity don't really matter; the size will be set based on the total of the gravities within the view you are using.  Ff the text is gravity 5 and the checkbox is gravity 1, the text will fill 84% of the view and the cb to 16%.  the same would happen using 50 and 10.  The total is 100%.